# How to plot a diagram look like the same this figure by Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

[image]

This is the figure I would like to draw by Tikz

Comment: What is the use of this diagram?

Comment: What is the meaning of this diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All credits to @ferahfeza for the original drawing, I just added the `intersections` library part, to draw the three orange vectors exactly parallel.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
      mybackground/.style={
            background rectangle/.style={fill=black},
            background grid/.style={draw=gray!80, step=10mm,  thin},
            show background rectangle,
            show background grid % after a filled background rectangle
            }
        }
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mybackground,>=stealth,thick]
        \draw [red,very thick,->](0,0) -- (8.5,0) node [above]{$x$};
        \draw [red,very thick,->](0,0) -- (0,6.5) node [right]{$t$};
        
        \foreach \x in {1,2,3}
            {
            \draw [cyan,->,name path global = {T\x}] (2*\x,0) --++ (0,6)node [above left]{$t^\prime$};
            \path [name path global = {P\x}] (0,2*\x) coordinate (R\x) --++ (-30:3*\x);
            \path [name intersections={of={P\x} and {T\x}, by={E\x}}];
            
            \draw [cyan,->] (2*\x,0) --++ (1.2,0)node [below]{$x^\prime$};
            \draw [green,->](2*\x,5) --++ (0.8,0)node[above]{$V$};
            
            \draw[orange,->] (R\x) node[below left]{$R_{\x}$} -- (E\x) node[right]{$E_{\x}$};
            \filldraw[orange]   (E\x) circle (1pt)
                                (R\x) circle (1pt);
            }           
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: vectors on blackboard]

Comment: Just edited my post to replace the code by a substantially shorter one, taking advantage of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: thank you very much !!!